# Is it possible to solve bi-objective model directly in GAMS?

Tags: gams-math

Is there any command that can solve multi objective model directly? 
I mean, without using weighted sum or epsilon constraint methods, can we solve multi objective  model in gams?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the epsilon constraint model in GAMS which is applicable in solving bi-objective optimization problems and finding the pareto optimal front.

```
$title Pareto optimal front determination

$onText
For more details please refer to Chapter 2 (Gcode2.16), of the following book:
Soroudi, Alireza. Power System Optimization Modeling in GAMS. Springer, 2017.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Model type: NLP
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Contributed by
Dr. Alireza Soroudi
IEEE Senior Member
email: alireza.soroudi@gmail.com
We do request that publications derived from the use of the developed GAMS code
explicitly acknowledge that fact by citing
Soroudi, Alireza. Power System Optimization Modeling in GAMS. Springer, 2017.
DOI: doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-62350-4
$offText

Variable of1, of2, x1, x2;
Equation eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4;

eq1.. 4*x1 - 0.5*sqr(x2) =e= of1;
eq2.. -sqr(x1) + 5*x2    =e= of2;
eq3.. 2*x1 + 3*x2        =l= 10;
eq4.. 2*x1 -   x2        =g=  0;

x1.lo = 1; x1.up = 2;
x2.lo = 1; x2.up = 3;

Model pareto1 / all /;

Set counter / c1*c21 /;
Scalar E;
Parameter report(counter,*), ranges(*);

solve pareto1 using nlp maximizing of1;
ranges('OF1max') = of1.l;
ranges('OF2min') = of2.l;

solve pareto1 using nlp maximizing of2;
ranges('OF2max') = of2.l;
ranges('OF1min') = of1.l;

loop(counter,
   E = (ranges('OF2max') - ranges('OF2min'))*(ord(counter) - 1)/(card(counter) - 1) + ranges('OF2min');
   of2.lo = E;
   solve pareto1 using nlp maximizing of1;
   report(counter,'OF1') = of1.l;
   report(counter,'OF2') = of2.l;
   report(counter,'E')   = E;
);
display report;
```